# Updating a nested record with new data in elm

Tags: list, immutability, record, elm

I have two pieces of JSON that I've successfully decoded sequentially. I would like to take the new `html_fragment` and update my existing `html_fragment`. Generally this would be simple but my data structure is giving me difficulties:

```
type PostDataContainer
    = PostDataContainer PostData


type alias PostData =
    { title : String
    , comments : List Comment
    }


type alias Comment =
    { comment_id : Int
    , html_fragment : String
    }


type alias CommentHtml =
    { id : Int
    , html_fragment : String
    }
```

I've just gotten `CommentHtml` and would like to update the existing `html_fragment` in `Comment`. This is what I have so far:

```
    MergeCommentHtml commentHtmlData ->
        case commentHtmlData of
            Err err ->
                Debug.log ("Error decoding CommentHtmlData" ++ toString err)
                    ( mdl, Cmd.none )

            Ok commentHtml ->
                case mdl.maybePostDataContainer of
                    Just (PostDataContainer postData) ->
                        let
                            updatedCommentData = -- I dont know how to calculate this?
                        in
                        ( { mdl | postData = { postData | comments = updatedCommentData } }, Cmd.none )
```

Note that `commentHtml` here is a `List CommentHtml`. Any thoughts on how to update my old `comment.html_fragment` with the new values in `commentHtml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `commentHtmlData` is a `List` according to a comment, I think the easiest approach is to convert it to a `Dict` keyed by `id`, then map over the existing comments looking for the `comment_id` in the dict. If it exists, replace `html_fragment`, if not then return the original unmodified:

```
let
    commentHtmlDict =
        commentHtmlData
            |> List.map (\c -> (c.id, c))
            |> Dict.fromList

    updatedCommentData =
        postData.comments
            |> List.map (\comment ->
                case Dict.get comment.comment_id commentHtmlDict of
                    Just commentHtml ->
                        { comment | html_fragment = commentHtml.html_fragment }

                    Nothing ->
                        comment
            )
```

Comment: Yes this is close! However `commentHtmlData` is a list. I'm getting a compile error `The type of commentHtmlData is: List CommentHtml`

Comment: Yeah, that's an essential piece of information :) I've updated the answer with a slightly modified suggestion.

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for thanks. I've never used `Dict` before... any thoughts on a solution without one?

Comment: You could use `List.Extra.find` from [elm-community/list-extra](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/latest), or just [implement it yourself](https://github.com/elm-community/list-extra/blob/master/src/List/Extra.elm#L556-L567). But a `Dict` will perform better (O(log n) vs O(n) lookup) which might be significant since you're going to search through it for every comment.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: 
just decode the data as it stands. When it's time to display it, arrange it appropriately via some function you write like `rawJsonDataToNicerData`.

Option 2:
Suppose you implement the following function:

```
-- given a new comment, and some PostData, return the new version of the PostData
updateData : CommentHtml -> PostData -> PostData

-- so now, assuming we can decode a CommentHtml with commentHtmlDeocder
-- we can do the following
dataUpdaterDecoder : Decoder (PostData -> PostData)
dataUpdaterDecoder 
   commentHtmlDecoder |> Decoder.andThen (\commentHtml -> updateData commentHtml)
```

Now wherever we were going to decode a  `commentHtmlDeocder` we can decode a `dataUpdaterDecoder` instead, and use a bunch of these to update our data.

Here is an example of a relational data decoder in action using the idea above:

https://ellie-app.com/3KWmyJmMrDsa1

Comment: I've given a thumbs up because the `andThen` is a good idea to try out. This doesn't exactly answer my question though... I'm not having trouble decoding it, the problem comes when I try to merge the two data sets based on id.

Comment: My answer shows how to update any data structure based on any other arbitrary json. I'm interested in how that isn't sufficient.

Comment: Maybe you should share more code or put it in an Ellie

Comment: I am interested in the details of what `updateData` would look like

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what your are trying to accomplish from start to end, and what part exactly is giving you trouble.

Comment: What is the type of the function you are trying to implement?

Comment: `CommentHtml -> PostData -> PostData`

Comment: I'm trying to provide a value for `updatedCommentData` in `MergeCommentHtml`